# In Hyperledger Fabric, is there a way to decode ledger data to human readable form?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I tried to use "peer" binary to fetch blocks from ledger.

```
peer channel fetch 2 --channelID mychannel
```

However these blocks are not in human readable form. Is there a way to decode the blocks to human readable form to view the transaction data?

Comment: You should be able to decode it with the Node Fabric SDK. See
https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/BlockDecoder.html#.decodeBlock__anchor for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using configtxlator binary that's included. For example:

```
configtxlator proto_decode --input the_one_you_fetched.pb --type common.Block--output human_readable.json
```

Comment: Thanks for this. could decode with configtxlator binary